# Array of months AS3 DATE()

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a stats page which shows a rolling 12 months of figures. I've created an array to hold the months and a for loop to populate the array starting with the current month as first element in the array

```
var myDate:Date = new Date();
for(var mn:uint=0; mn<12;mn++){
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth()+1);
    trace("statMonth +: "+ myDate.month);
    }
```

The trace produces this:

staMonth: 6
staMonth: 7
staMonth: 8
staMonth: 9
staMonth: 10
staMonth: 11
staMonth: 0
staMonth: 2
staMonth: 3
staMonth: 4
staMonth: 5
staMonth: 6
staMonth: 7

I had to do a double take.. Where is month 1? Is it me? Am I being totally stupid?

When I amend the for loop thus:

```
for(var mn:uint=0; mn<20;mn++){
```

it traces:
staMonth: 6
staMonth: 7
staMonth: 8
staMonth: 9
staMonth: 10
staMonth: 11
staMonth: 0
staMonth: 2
staMonth: 3
staMonth: 4
staMonth: 5
staMonth: 6
staMonth: 7
staMonth: 8
staMonth: 9
staMonth: 10
staMonth: 11
staMonth: 0
**staMonth: 1**
staMonth: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because February only has 28, sometimes 29, days. You keep adding 1 month to the current date, which is 30th of June. After 7 cycles the date will be 30th of January. Adding one month probably results in the 1st of March.

Comment: now I'm confused and have amended my question so show my cofusion... why does it pick up month 1 on the second iteration?

Comment: @Filious: When the first cycle of the loop skips February, it continues the loop with the 1st of March. So the next date values will be 1st of April, 1st of May, 1st of June, and so on. When it reaches 1st of January, and you add another 1 month, the next value will be 1st of February, thus it won't skip the month again.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to include the `date` property.

```
var myDate:Date = new Date();
for(var mn:uint=0; mn<20;mn++)
{
    myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth()+1);
    Wonderfl.log("statMonth: "+ myDate.month + " " + myDate.date);
}
```

As you can see in the results below, the missing February (see [Ruud Lender's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38120694/4347580)) causes an offset in the `date` value, which on the second pass (in the next year) causes February to show up.

```
statMonth: 6 30
statMonth: 7 30
statMonth: 8 30
statMonth: 9 30
statMonth: 10 30
statMonth: 11 30
statMonth: 0 30
statMonth: 2 2
statMonth: 3 2
statMonth: 4 2
statMonth: 5 2
statMonth: 6 2
statMonth: 7 2
statMonth: 8 2
statMonth: 9 2
statMonth: 10 2
statMonth: 11 2
statMonth: 0 2
statMonth: 1 2
statMonth: 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realise that the date() counted days when referencing the month only... I'm not a developer, just someone learning. My solution is, for anyone having the same battle is: myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() +1,1); ......thus setting the day of the month to 1...thanks to you both

Comment: It's interesting to see it jumps from the 30th of January to the *2nd* of March... I would've expected it to jump the the **1st** of March.